# Unable to access another page via url in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to access /orders via url "localhost:3000/orders" but i am unable to do so.

here is my app.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import './App.sass';

import Home from "./components/homepage.component"
import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import Contact from "./components/contact.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";
import OrderList from "./components/orderlist.component"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Switch>
      <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <Route path="/homepage" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/create" component={Contact} />
      <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      <Route path="/orders" component={OrderList} />
      <Redirect from= '/' to='/homepage' />
      </div>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am using `<Redirect>` tag to redirect my app directly to homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to import switch

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
```

And also Switch should be capitalized

**EDIT 1**
Try to change your code accordingly:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import './App.sass';

import Home from "./components/homepage.component"
import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import Contact from "./components/contact.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";
import OrderList from "./components/orderlist.component"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/homepage" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/create" component={Contact} />
      <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      <Route path="/orders" component={OrderList} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey James, I'm still unable to do that, the moment i type "localhost:3000/orders" in my browser, it redirects back to homepage.

Comment: @BaidManus Try  adding `import{ withRouter } from 'react-router-native';` and `export default withRouter(App)`

Comment: No luck even after that.

Comment: @BaidManus Weird. I tried reproducing it on my environment and I was getting no issues. Would you mind updating your post exactly the same? Include all the imports and everything.

Comment: Can you try removing the Switch and remove the redirect? Instead replace it to `<Route exact path="/"`. I updated my answer. @BaidManus

Answer (score 0):

you have to be exporting from `orderList.js` like `export default OrderList;`

and inside your `app.js` you need to import orderList like `import OrderList from "./components/orderlist";` and make sure your `Switch` component is getting imported.

Comment: Hey Arun, I am exporting from OrderList.component.js "export default class OrderList extends React.Component{......."  Still I'm still unable to do that, the moment i type "localhost:3000/orders" in my browser, it redirects back to homepage. –

Comment: That is correct, import inside app.js, as i mentioned, and please ensure <Switch /> is imported.

Comment: I did import Switch and added it :) as well

Comment: so okay, what is the acutall error message you are getting, can you share a snapshot?

Comment: So, there's no error, it is some routing problem, "localhost:3000/<any compoenenet>" is working when i'm removing <Redirect> tag. But not with the tag included in the code.